# Typescript function to accept array or single instance of constructor and return list

Tags: typescript, generics, entity, entity-component-system

**EDIT**: [reproducible link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQGEIBbSJYFOAbwCg44BnYGAURQRgE8AuOACgBumADYBXYH3zsYnLgEo4AXgB8cQRAQATANz04AcxYy5ffotUET3PQF9atUJFiIUaLLisduNfQ2yk5JQwjHyYSFwA2gC6dg5O0PABSIzwwXIAyizKcBQA7nBZMAA80t5cKuZ6juCJcNgimIyMcMRkEBQoxQAqcKCoSFotEABGAFbA2DBqCGQiwCTBLUSBHcG%20DGBQCMKocAD66dxS1lxwAD5wYoPA6MjAuvr6zGzlQqISJ%20WKdAwMCOgBDAABYIRgAOkO5WUSiU6g%20wB%20fj%20UBYYigSD0fzg9mxyJBYMhRzOcOE4mAWJxTwYRlesm45i%209LOvxRaIxcAJEKhzIAhJTcXB9FsIGBQnBupT9MlUlAxFNoPwRWKAPx8bpI7Fc8HKlpw1nY8FG3VwJoS5GC%20z2GrOJKNZpwABqCGAeTaQSo-UoQ1aq06JXCFQ29Q6svlMEVurCEU1f0YYjAaCVUFFjHkAto1oSLgaTRa3Sg4UY6GgJHda09IAGPvL-uKgbUrJlMDlCqgydTatNMeDDHjifb6f0VocAHpRxKABL4DISgCaAAV8AA5ADicAAIgB5VgZZcAcl6AHUtwAlADStHQ1ymCA6hmM3hdjAAQlxa8Een0q96Wh%20ug2lQBGQ3RcImfD5AIRrgpgUAGOKgYxBYai9JcACCUCFlwxSQfw0GwfB0ZRNEyESio8hMnIMTBs2IYgWBwB6nAGFYeCYIsZgXD8MBYCgYmigqnRvEMXAfCRDxfHALE%20iojA6JIMxmGceC6ApiQ-DEkU4JkhIjDmPIyIqQgIioO2eCWAabJyRywDgjxFYhOCjCkMA3HKGoEkMRCzmLNxgSSe59SuKk4S4BAgKefxBnYrYQ7WuOU4zvOS5rpuO6zieF5Xjesj3rS1jPm%20-4wN0wKYDAR7QAA1owX5eoMLS4fhcEIRESGBcV9YRCoQH%20Qx6oXIpWE9ORlHcNRlm0ZFjE5BxXBsYwc1%20fR-FwIJ02iXA4l9Ym0nYrJ8lDcpqmkBp5RaTpjH6cihp3CZSbmWotn2f63kuW5ljTW9vkbZ9wUwKFwDhUJknyGDmZjhOaAplAtC0YILpun6wQFTNcL5U%20jFFcjKD8JEzqusVAA0EqFikJZQGWOMwCR1QJUgEB9Jh0Bw6G8AI4T1Oo4wlVQDVOQY-ShXvtTpXlbzNV4wTSPtP6JMFkWFNU7LwS07QQA) to typescript's playground

I also found a solution that is in the link as well, though I don't actually understand why my first one doesn't work if anyone still wants to educate me.

TLDR;

this does not work

`getEntitiesByComponent<T extends Component<any>>(compType: new (...args: any[]) => T | Array<new (...args: any[]) => T>): IEntity[] {`

this works

`getEntitiesByComponent<T extends new (...args: any[]) => Component<any>>(compType: T | Array<T>): IEntity[]`

---

**EDIT 2**

Code from reproducible link

```
export interface IComponent {
  setEntity: (value: IEntity) => void;
  getEntity: () => IEntity;
}

export interface IEntity {
    components: any[];
}

export const entitySet = new Set<IEntity>();

export class Component<T extends object> implements IComponent {
  private _entity: IEntity | undefined;
  
  setEntity(value: IEntity) {
    if (this._entity === value) {
      return;
    }
    
    this._entity = value;
  }
  
  getEntity(): IEntity {
    return this._entity!;
  }
  
  props: T;
  
  constructor(props?: T) {
    this.props = {
      ...props as T
    }
  }
}

export class ViewComponent extends Component<any> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
  }
}

export class TransformComponent extends Component<any> {
  constructor(props?: any) {
    super();
  }
}

// THIS TYPING DOESN'T WORK
function getEntitiesByComponent<T extends Component<any>>(compType: new (...args: any[]) => T | Array<new (...args: any[]) => T>): IEntity[] {
  const compTypes = Array.isArray(compType) ? compType : [compType];
  return Array.from(entitySet.values())
    .filter(e => {
      return e.components.some(c => compTypes.some(compType => c instanceof compType))
    });
}

// THIS TYPING DOES WORK
function getEntitiesByComponentThatWorks<T extends new (...args: any[]) => Component<any>>(compType: T | Array<T>): IEntity[] {
    const compTypes = Array.isArray(compType) ? compType : [compType];
    return Array.from(entitySet.values())
        .filter(e => e.components.some(c => compTypes.some(compType => c instanceof compType)))
}

// error
const viewComponentEntities = getEntitiesByComponent([ViewComponent, TransformComponent]);

// no error
const viewComponentEntitiesWorks = getEntitiesByComponentThatWorks([ViewComponent, TransformComponent]);
```

---

**ORIGINAL**

I'm trying to define a function that accepts single instance of- or an array of instances of objects that subclass a single parent class.

```
// EntityManager.ts

/**
 * this func should receive either a single instance of a constructor that returns a
 * Component<any> or an array of the same and should return only entities that have a
 * component that is an instance of one of them.
**/
getEntitiesByComponent<T extends Component<any>>(compType: new (...args: any[]) => T | Array<new (...args: any[]) => T>): IEntity[] {
  const compTypes = Array.isArray(compType) ? compType : [compType];
  return Array.from(this._entitySet.values())
    .filter(e => {
      return e.components.some(c => compTypes.some(compType => c instanceof compType))
    });
}
```

ViewComponent and TransformComponent both extend Component.

```
// ViewComponent.ts

import { Component } from '../components/component';

export type ViewComponentProps = {
  alias: string;
  src: string;
}

export class ViewComponent extends Component<ViewComponentProps> {
  constructor(props: ViewComponentProps) {
    super(props);
  }
}
```

```
// TransformComponent.ts
import { Component } from './component';

export type TransformComponentProps = {
  x: number;
  y: number;
  scaleX?: number;
  scaleY?: number;
  zIndex?: number;
}

export class TransformComponent extends Component<TransformComponentProps> {
  private static _defaultProps: TransformComponentProps = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    scaleX: 1,
    scaleY: 1,
    zIndex: 0,
  };
  
  constructor(props?: TransformComponentProps) {
    super({
      ...TransformComponent._defaultProps,
      ...props
    });
  }
}
```

When I invoke it like so

```
const viewComponentEntities = EntityManager.getInstance().getEntitiesByComponent([ViewComponent, TransformComponent]);
```

Typescript gives me this error

```
TS2345: Argument of type
(typeof TransformComponent | typeof ViewComponent)[]
is not assignable to parameter of type
new (...args: any[]) => Component<any> | (new (...args: any[]) => Component<any>)[]
Type
(typeof TransformComponent | typeof ViewComponent)[]
provides no match for the signature
new (...args: any[]): Component<any> | (new (...args: any[]) => Component<any>)[]
```

I'm not understanding why I'm getting the error or how to prevent it.

Comment: @jcalz added link, and coincidentally found a typing that worked, but not clear to me why

Comment: • Thanks.  Please also put the [mre] as plaintext in the question itself, not just as a link (a link is a great supplement but it's not sufficient by itself). • Is there a reason `Component` is generic if you're just using `any` everywhere? Assuming that you're not asking about it, maybe you could make it nongeneric for the example? • Is there a reason `getEntitiesByComponent()` is generic? You're not using `T` anywhere that matters. The unmotivated generics in the question seem like they're just distractions. Could you either motivate them or remove them?

Comment: (See prev ocmment) • Is it possible that you're just confused about operator precedence and parenthesization? `() => A | B` and `(()=>A) | B` are different. If I put in [the proper parentheses](https://tsplay.dev/wjop2N) things seem to work. If that's the whole issue I could write an answer but... it kind of feels like a typo?  Maybe it's still worthwhile for people to read about such things, though. Let me know how you'd like to proceed.

Comment: @jcalz oh wow; no, not confused, just didn't even realize the mistake in syntax until it was pointed out. Thank you!

As to the generics, I paired down the code and left out where they were being used. So i guess I could have removed them from the example as well.

Comment: So, if you're not confused, then it's just a typo? Do you think it would be helpful for others to leave this question here with an answer about parentheses? Or should we close it as "not reproducible / caused by typo"?

Comment: I've written the solution and will mark as answer when I am able.

Comment: Ah, well, I would have been happy to write an answer but that's also fine. Have a good day.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257075/discussion-between-kamcknig-and-jcalz).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With @jcalz help, it was pointed out I simply had a syntax error.

`getEntitiesByComponent<T extends Component<any>>(compType: new (...args: any[]) => T | Array<new (...args: any[]) => T>): IEntity[]`

My type was looking for a constructor that returned `T` or `Array<new (...args: any[]) => T>`

rather than a single constructor `(new (...args: any[]) => T)` or array of them `Array<new (...args: any[]) => T>`

so this now works

`getEntitiesByComponent<T extends Component<any>>(compType: (new (...args: any[]) => T) | Array<new (...args: any[]) => T>): IEntity[]`